# App.config in Test Projects

Tags: .net, asp.net, tdd, .net-assembly

I'm building an ASP.NET app in VS2010. I have a number of separate assemblies (class libraries) and corresponding Test projects for each.

In one of the class libraries I use an App.config file to store settings. The assembly itself uses the following code to retrieve settings:

```
 string tmp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySetting"];
```

The problem is that when I try to create a Unit Test in a separate test project, the test does not pick up the setting in the App.config file. If I COPY the App.config file into the Test project, it works.

How can I ensure that each assembly uses its own copy of an App.config file. It would introduce problems if I had to copy config files around. There's an additional problem because there may be multiple config files, one per assembly - how could they all co-exist in a single test project anyway?

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Well, if you need a *App.config* file shared across several projects, I would simply "Add as Link" the original *App.config* file in each project.

Let's say you have **ProjectA** with the original *App.config*. Then you have **ProjectATest1** and **ProjectATest2**. In each of the *TestX* project:

1. right click on the solution name in Visual Studio
2. select "Add Existing Item"
3. navigate to the **ProjectA** *App.config* and select it
4. click in the "Add" button down arrow
5. select "Add as Link"

It'll create a *App.config* shortcut in each *TestX* project. If you change it, it will change everywhere.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Didn't occur to me you could link files between projects, good to know, but would it get processed and copied correctly...

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to work very well. Nice to get a direct answer, rather than just an opinion.

Comment: Nice to know it helped. There are other ways of importing settings between _App.config_ files but when all the _App.config_ files should have the same contents this is the simplest and elegant one. I'm using this in testing, too.

Comment: BTW I'm referencing a config file in the MAIN web app. While I'd like to keep settings isolated to each assembly, I appreciate the necessity to keep them centralised with the current limitations of the technology. I may work on a different scheme to store settings so that I can truly isolate assembly behaviour. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

First up, if you're doing unit testing, then you probably want to look at mocking out the configuration, rather than reading it anyway.

If you really want to make the config available (I've done it for integration tests in the past), then you can add a post-build step to your assemblys (I'm assuming a 1-1 mapping of assembly to test-assemblies).

The post build step (on your test assembly) would look something like this:

```
  copy /y  "<path to your assembly under test>.dll.config" "$(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).dll.config"
```

Essentially, you're copying the app.config that has been renamed for you by visual studio for the assembly you're testing, to match the expected configuration name for your test assembly.

Comment: Thank you - I'll keep this in mind should we need to do that. Could be useful for very specific cases where we need to expedite testing.

Answer (score 3):

One should not have config files for the assemblies. If you do so, every application will end up having one config file per dll/reference project.

The assemblies pick up the config values from the application (Windows/Web) context in which they are loaded.

So if you have an WebApp, the assemblies would use WebApp's web.config file to read the config values. Similarly if you have a Windows App/Unit Test app, the libraries should read the values from app.config.

Please read this related question - [C#.NET Compiling the settings.settings file from various projects in a solution into 1 config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644648/c-net-compiling-the-settings-settings-file-from-various-projects-in-a-solution-i/5644678#5644678)

Comment: The comments from my conversation with Andrew appear to have disappeared. My original question was not "how can I have multiple config files" it was "how do I make config accessible from test projects". He proceeded to explain why I was wrong to test configuration at all. That is incorrect. Then the comments were removed...

Comment: I don't have that context, so can't comment. Anyway, I would suggest to use a single config file. Try and avoid having config files for assemblies.

Comment: BTW you're intimating that assemblies should behave in isolation for all things EXCEPT their configuration? That's not correct. Ideally, assemblies should be ENTIRELY self-contained in ALL respects. When my ASP.NET app utilises an assembly to access a database, the responsibility of configuring WHICH db should lie with the assmbly, not the web application. This percolates into all aspects of maintenance and deployment. I understand this may be a failing of the .NET development environment but you can't say it's the way to do things.

Comment: But, Andrew, where are MY comments? You did not say you were going to delete anything. Forget about it. I got a great answer from someone who knows.

Comment: Just a suggestion (don't take it otherwise). If I have my connection string defined in the assembly, and the database server changes - Won't I have to recompile my assembly. People are reverse engineer to get the connection string and other information. Anyway, feel free to use whatever you feel is correct :). Cheers !!!

Comment: lol @ Andrew. So, "playground tactics" it is then? I'm certain you don't make that much money :) I want to keep the spirit of configuration i.e. prevent recompilation or redeployment, allow admin configuration to influence behaviour, etc. All this while keeping assembly-specific config tightly linked to the assembly. I'm not suggesting anything breaking best-practices in any way. I just want a solution that does it all ;-)