# Exception "The SMTP host was not specified" where I'm using SpecifiedPickupDirectory in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, tdd, sendmail

I have in my controller action (I removet try/catch block for more clear code):

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendMessage(ContactViewModel model)
    {          
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

                var administrator = new MailAddress("xxxx@gmail.com");
                var customer = new MailAddress(model.Email, model.Name);

                message.Bcc.Add(customer);
                message.Bcc.Add(administrator);
                message.Subject = "Message Subject";
                message.Body = model.Message;

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();                    
                client.Send(message);

        }

        return PartialView("_ContactPartial", model);
    }
```

The action works correctly, the info about host are in web.config.

I want create unit test's for this action. I created in my project with test web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\MailTest\"/>        
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

And there is basic unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ContactControllerTest_SendMessage_PartialView()
    {
        //Arrange
        var controller = new ContactController();

        //Act
        var result = controller.SendMessage(contactViewModel) as PartialViewResult;

        //Asset
        Assert.AreEqual("_ContactPartial", result.ViewName");
    }
```

In the line

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
```

I have exception:  The SMTP host was not specified. Why it need it if in my web.config I selected SpecifiedPickupDirectory as delivery method?

Comment: Probably the `App.Config` is missing... [How to use App.Config in Test Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674619/app-config-in-test-projects)

Comment: @OldFox In this topic is about share same web.config between two projects but I have got two web.config files. First is normal with host, username, password etc to send mail, second (inserted here) added only to test project for save mail as file on the disk.