# Specflow - Unable to read from app.config file as ConfigurationManager is returning null values

Tags: c#, mstest, specflow, .net-core-3.1

I have created a Console application project(proj name: **ConsoleApp**) with **.Net core 3.1**. I have added a specflow feature file where in I have defined my test scenario and also a class file which has my test case

```
[Given(@"I have started the application")]
public void GivenIHaveStartedTheApplication()
{
    TestClass testClass1 = new TestClass();
    testClass1.ReadConfigValues();
}
```

Also, I have added an App.config in the same ConsoleApp Project which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="User" value="Admin" />
    <add key="Password" value="nopassword" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**TestClass** is a C# class file which is residing in a different Class Library project(proj name: **TestProject**) with **.Net Framework 4.7**. This project has been referenced by ConsoleApp

Code for TestClass  is as below

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void ReadConfigValues()
    {
        string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["User"];
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing here is that the values for both user and password are returned as null. Basically ConfigurationManager.AppSettings has a count equal to zero.

Could anyone point out if I'm missing anything?

Comment: Why do you need `app.config` in .net core app?

Comment: The configuration used by your application cannot be read by the test framework, which is running as a separate process. You can either add the configuration file to the test project itself, or engage in some heavy-handed reflection to retarget things, or step away from using `ConfigurationManager` and refactor configuration code into its own class. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/344069/4137916), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5674619/4137916), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48666780/4137916) and probably other questions that I missed (not sure which is the best dupe).

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I would like to have my application configurable.
The settings added under app.config to be accessible for other class libraries

Comment: What about `appsettings.json`?

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert for the insight